# Windows Authentication Failed on changing the domain server

Tags: sql-server

I had installed SQL server 2012 using windows authentication and attached a database that is on my C drive. Domain server failed and we have to rebuild domain server. The domain server name is now changed to new name. When I try to log in to the SQL 2012 Studio,  I can not log in and I am getting an error `login failed for the user`.

All we did was add a letter to the domain server. Could someone direct how to correct the issue as SQL server 2012 studio is not allow me to login?

Thanking you, 
Hem

Comment: you *rebuilt* the domain server?  Seems something might have been missed.

Comment: are you able to login with SA?

Answer (score 1):

This is about more than just changing the name. Domain memberships involve cyrptographic signatures that must also be replaced. All of the machines in your domain will need to re-join. You'll have a new account on your own machine. Yep, it sucks, and this is one reason why you should always keep at least 2 DCs.

Assuming you don't know any other account info, the only way to get back into the existing Sql Server instance is to [restart Sql Server in single-user mode and connect as a local administrator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-2017) After you've done this, you'll need to recreate all of your logins.

Since you'll be recreating accounts and permission anyway, another option is to use this as opportunity to upgrade to a more recent Sql Server version. Sql Server 2012 is already major 3 releases behind. Shut down and uninstall the existing Sql Server instance. Install the new version of the Sql Server, where you know the `sa` login, and then attach to the old database mdf files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to login with `SQL authentication? (with SA account)`

SQL:

```
DROP LOGIN [OldDomain\UserName]
GO

CREATE LOGIN [NewDomain\UserName] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [NewDomain\UserName]
GO
```

Then you will be able to login with your new domain name. (Make sure you change the domain name and username in the above SQL)

If you need to recover your sa password? Check this article [How to recover SA password](http://v-consult.be/2011/05/26/recover-sa-password-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2/)